# Environment variable to override GTK icon theme

Tags: environment-variables, theme, icons

There is an environment variable available for overwriting current system GTK theme, `GTK_THEME`. Is there anything available for icon theme as well as for overwriting current icon theme?

Comment: Relevant answer on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/810714/844221